# flex: 1 not scrolling on safari?

Tags: html, css, safari, flexbox

i have this code:

```
.parent { 
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

this is the child i want to scroll:

```
.child {
    flex: 1 1 0%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    margin-bottom: 84px;
}
```

the child will contain multiple divs and this is the code of the .grandchild

```
.grandChild {
    align-items: flex-end;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

everything works fine in google but not safari? why?
the html:

```
<div class="parent>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="grandChild">
     text
    </div>
    <div class="grandChild">
     text
    </div>
    <div class="grandChild">
     text
    </div>
    <div class="grandChild">
     text
    </div>
    <div class="grandChild">
     text
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="otherchild" />
 </div>
```

no matter how many grandChild on safari it will not scroll, they stuck up on each other, but on chrome everything is ok?

Comment: pls share html also

Comment: will check and let you knoe

Comment: you should add grandChild also ooverflow-y: scroll;

Comment: the child is the one i want to scroll but it's not working on safari

Comment: I had a similar error and for me the problem was `flex: 1 1 0%`. This issue was only with Opera and Safari. I changed with `flex: 1 1 auto` and it works perfectly.
Hope it can help! :)

Answer (score 0):

you should add max-height for child div

**css**

```
.child {
    flex: 1 1 0%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    margin-bottom: 84px;
    max-height:50px;
}
```